# Get 4 figures in each rows using Revtex4-2

Tags: two-column, revtex

I have 20 figures, which need to include in a two-column style paper. The figures should be added at the top of the corresponding page, with 4 figures in each row. I look for something like this [image]

I try to use  `figure*` but the figures don't appear
My use packages section is as follows:

```
\documentclass[showpacs, pra,twocolumn,preprintnumbers ,amsmath, amssymb, superscriptaddress, aps]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\usepackage{amssymb}  % More symbols
\usepackage{bbold}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{pifont}   % Ding symbols
\usepackage{graphicx} % Include figure files
\graphicspath{{Figures/}}
\usepackage{dcolumn}  % Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}       % bold math
\usepackage{multirow} % Table functions
\usepackage{placeins}% For making floats not move around everywhere
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\newpage
\begin{figure*}[t]
    \centering
\includegraphics[width=1.7in]{Fig00}\includegraphics[width=1.7in]{Fig0}\includegraphics[width=1.7in]{Fig9}
\includegraphics[width=1.7in]{Fig10}\includegraphics[width=1.7in]{Fig11}
\includegraphics[width=1.7in]{Fig12}\includegraphics[width=1.7in]{Fig13}
\includegraphics[width=1.7in]{Fig14}\includegraphics[width=1.7in]{Fig15}
\includegraphics[width=1.7in]{Fig16}\includegraphics[width=1.7in]{Fig17}
\includegraphics[width=1.7in]{Fig18}\includegraphics[width=1.7in]{Fig19}
\includegraphics[width=1.7in]{Fig20}\includegraphics[width=1.7in]{Fig21}\includegraphics[width=1.7in]{Fig22}\includegraphics[width=1.7in]{Fig23}
\includegraphics[width=1.7in]{Fig24}\includegraphics[width=1.7in]{Fig25}\includegraphics[width=1.7in]{Fig26}\includegraphics[width=1.7in]{Fig27}
\includegraphics[width=1.7in]{Fig28}
\caption{}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Maybe try with the `strip` environment, from the `cuted` package (`sttools` bundle)?

Comment: why are some images .45\linewidth and some 1.7in? your description seems to suggest they are all teh same width?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle just a mistake i keep in width

Comment: @Bernard Please can you explain more Thanks

Comment: I mean, loading cuted with `\usepackage{cuted}` (check `sttools` is installed on your system) and replace the `figure*` environment with `\begin{strip}\begin{figure} … \end{figure}\end{strip}`.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to include the images, although if you want to adjust the vertical space you could leave a blank line every 4 and add some `\vspace{...}` a `figure*` always appears at the earliest on the page after it appears in the souce file, so you may need to move it earlier in the source to get it to appear where you want.

[image]

```
\documentclass[showpacs, pra,twocolumn,preprintnumbers ,amsmath, amssymb, superscriptaddress, aps]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Include figure files

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[!tp]
    \centering
\includegraphics[width=1.7in]{example-image}
\includegraphics[width=1.7in]{example-image}
\includegraphics[width=1.7in]{example-image}
\includegraphics[width=1.7in]{example-image}
\includegraphics[width=1.7in]{example-image}
\includegraphics[width=1.7in]{example-image}
\includegraphics[width=1.7in]{example-image}
\includegraphics[width=1.7in]{example-image}
\includegraphics[width=1.7in]{example-image}
\includegraphics[width=1.7in]{example-image}
\includegraphics[width=1.7in]{example-image}
\includegraphics[width=1.7in]{example-image}
\includegraphics[width=1.7in]{example-image}
\includegraphics[width=1.7in]{example-image}
\includegraphics[width=1.7in]{example-image}
\includegraphics[width=1.7in]{example-image}
\includegraphics[width=1.7in]{example-image}
\includegraphics[width=1.7in]{example-image}
\includegraphics[width=1.7in]{example-image}
\includegraphics[width=1.7in]{example-image}
\caption{a caption}
\end{figure*}

some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 

some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 

some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 

some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 

some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 

some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 

some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 

some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 

some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 

some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 

some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 

some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 

\end{document}
```

Note your example had missing `}` and used a figure names that are not generally available so could not be run.

Answer (score 1):

Using `caption` with `revtex4` (any version) is not recommended. You can load

```
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
```

if you need subfloats, which is not the case in your situation.

My suggestion is to locally define a helper command in order to avoid long repetition of data and make it easy to add the small descriptions above the images.

It's up to you to place the entire `\begin{figure*}...\end{figure*}` construction somewhere between paragraphs that are typeset on the page before the one you want the images to appear.

Note. The package `kantlipsum` and the `\kant` commands just provide filler text for seeing the object in context. Don't use them in your document.

[image]

Comment: thank you so much it's work good now but still, the problem of placement figs shows up in the bottom of the document I try with ```\begin{figure*}[H][h][ht!][htbp!]``` and no results, I want figures where I would like them.

Comment: @Chan13 you can not have h or H with spanning figures the span has to come at the top of the page.

Comment: @Chan13 Besides `figure*` only appearing at top or bottom, it would be a very hard task accommodating such a big object in the middle a page. And, even if this were possible, the two-column format would make for very awkward reading.